Jura J7 no water coming out
The coffee from my J7 Impressa started to only drip out of the machine recently and the end result is also not as much as it should be. I checked there‘s no water in the tray but I noticed the coffee grounds fell right behind the container. The pump sounds differently, somehow less noisy but I‘m not sure it is related. It also sounds like there‘s a vacuum created in the machine that is released at the end of the process with a quiet „pfff“ sound.
Does anyone know if these symptoms point to a certain problem? I think it could be the pump or a blockage in the pipes.
